# Dropdown with autocomplete overlaps with other dropdown with autocomplete or a radio button in a repeated field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

In a WordPress website I use a form plugin which have incorporated the "chosen jQuery plugin" (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)".

If my form I use a repeated field option which have included a dropdown with autocomplete ON (the chosen jQuery plugin). **From second repeat** it start to overlaps with the next dropdown which have autocomplete on. The strange behavior also apply if intersect with a radio button field too, again, only starting from second repeat!

[image: See error]

Link to form: https://www.beclean.info/test

I do a lot of CSS investigation, I try to apply z-index, overflow hidden, position relative but the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `.chosen-drop` add position and z-index it will works

```
.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop{
    z-index:1000!important;
    position:static!important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Must to add with !important the z-index & position: static. 
@Solved!

Comment: I mark this answer as "undo" because Chosen has updated and the solution stopped working. Now with this solution the dropdown field will not close after selection.

Comment: @mariusfv what problem you faced now?

Comment: Udhay - Here: https://www.beclean.info/test at field "The dropdown list with aucomplete on" => because is position static (because Chosen plugin updated) after select an value the dropdown stay open, not close.

Comment: @mariusfv did you resolved? this link works fine now https://www.beclean.info/test

Comment: @ Udhay, this code .chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop{ solve the issue. What is strange: with ".chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop"space_here"{ doesn't work, but without that space everything works fine! I hate when developers at upgrades change classes or ID's, is not a good policy!

Comment: while updating they have to add new feature, if they keep change in exists it may affect our application. So you have to test if your link getting updates...