# CSS position static force Chosen dropdown with autocomplete not to close after selection are performed

Tags: css, jquery-chosen

Here: [Dropdown with autocomplete overlaps with other dropdown with autocomplete or a radio button in a repeated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528705/dropdown-with-autocomplete-overlaps-with-other-dropdown-with-autocomplete-or-a-r/54528862#54528862)

I encountered an problem with overlaps, from second repeat it start to overlaps with the next dropdown which have autocomplete on. The strange behavior also apply if intersect with a radio button field too, again, only starting from second repeat!

The provided solution works for a while, till Chosen plugin made an update. Now the position static force the dropdown field not to close after selection:

```
.chosen-drop{
 z-index:1000!important;
 position:static!important;
}
```

**Link to form**: https://www.beclean.info/test

I've try:

```
.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop {
z-index:1000!important;
position:static!important;
}
```

but with this solution it start to overlaps again from second repeat if he meets another dropdown with autocomplete.

How to keep position static (I need this to not overlaps with other field) **but** field to close after selection are made?

Comment: That seems to be due to the fact that `.chosen-results` stays populated with all the possible options, they just get hidden somehow, but keep demanding their space. Things are different when you actually _type_ into the field instead of selecting an option via click - then this list gets reduced to only the matching items (which in your example will be at most one in any case), all others are removed. Not sure if this _can_ be solved using CSS alone, you might need to add JavaScript to correctly handle this situation.

Comment: Till Chosen update position static and z-index applied to class chosen-drop do theirs job, force the container to not overlaps over other fields and selection working. I do not know what other CSS properties has add Chosen plugin after update that isn't compatible with position static. If works before should work now too.